# Error during npm run build - (plugin rpt2) Error: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, rollupjs

[my error during run command] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPnbq.png)

my rollup.config.js file:

Expected build Dist. file for my library but facing this error.
#build

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "�" character indicates that the file was not encoded properly. Try opening the file in a text editor and making sure that it's saved with a UTF-8 encoding.

You may need to update or implement Babel configuration to include the necessary plugins for importing non-JavaScript files.

If you already have, install `npm install --save-dev babel-runtime babel-plugin-transform-runtime`, then add the `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` plugin to your Babel configuration

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ]
}
```